# Issue with Netsuite saved search formula

Tags: oracle, formula, netsuite

I keep getting an invalid expression. Does anyone know why?

This is my query:

```
case when {systemnotes.field}is 'Discontinued' then {systemnotes.date} else '' end
```

Comment: would you be able to provide more details on the error? As someone not experienced with netsuite, it seems like there is a missing space after ...field}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use
CASE WHEN {systemnotes.filed} LIKE 'discontinued' THEN {systemnotes.date} ' ' END

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the keyword `IS` with the equality operator `=` to test for equality between `{systemnotes.field}` and `'Discontinued'`.  Also check the formula type to ensure it matches the data type returned.